# Cannot use hsqldb connection from app, but unit test work

Tags: java, spring-mvc, hsqldb

I have an app that is meant to write to a DB.  I'm working with hsqldb for development.

I have a unit test that can write to a DB with the `insertToDB()` method:

```
@Test
public void writeTest() throws SQLException {
    LocationImpl li = new LocationImpl();
    li.setName("TestName");
    li.setState("PA");
    li.setLattitude(100);
    li.setLongitude(200);
    LocationDAOImpl.insertIntoDB(li);
    ResultSet rs = LocationDAOImpl.getAllLocations();
    int i = 0;
            while (rs.next()){
        i++;
        if (i==591) { assertEquals("TestName", rs.getString(7)); }
    }
}
```

When I call it here, I get the following error.

`java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/Users/my/hsqldb/dir`:

Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addLocation", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addLocation(@ModelAttribute("LocationImpl")LocationImpl locationImpl, 
   ModelMap model) throws SQLException {
     logger.info("Form submission method called");
     model.addAttribute("name", locationImpl.getName());

     LocationDAOImpl.insertIntoDB(locationImpl);
     return new ModelAndView("result", "command", locationImpl);
   }
```

Any thoughts on why the connection works from jUnit, but not from the webapp?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because the HSQLDB JDBC driver is on the test classpath, but not on the runtime classpath.